# ASP server tag and Jquery.each

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I want to iterate through a content and let say this content has 4 textbox

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ClientIDMode="Static" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" class="Tester">
            Property ID:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PersonIDLabel1" runat="server" class="PersonalIDLabel1" onBlur="textBlur(event)" />
            <br />
            LastName:
            <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onBlur="textBlur(event);" />
            <br />
            FirstName:
            <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" onBlur="textBlur(event);"/>
            <br />
            Appraisal Comapny:
            <asp:TextBox ID="HireDateTextBox" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" onBlur="textBlur(event);"/>
            <br />
            Appraisal value:
            <asp:TextBox ID="EnrollmentTextBox" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" onBlur="textBlur(event);"/>
            <br />
```

and I want to use jquery to get all the value if the textbox, here is my code:

```
$("#FeaturedContent").each(function (index) {
            console.log($(this).val());  
        });
```

I also tried

```
$(".Tester").each(function (index) {
            console.log($(this).val()); 

        });

$("#MainContent").each(function (index) {
           console.log($(this).val()); 

        });

$("#Content").each(function (index) {
           console.log($(this).val()); 

        });

$("#TextBox").each(function (index) {
           console.log($(this).val()); 

        });
```

any ideas? Can I even get ASP tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `asp:Content` server control does not produce html for itself. Simply wrap what is inside of this control in a div:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ClientIDMode="Static" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" class="Tester">
<div id="wrapper">
  Property ID:
  <asp:TextBox ID="PersonIDLabel1" runat="server" class="PersonalIDLabel1"  onBlur="textBlur(event)" />
  <br />
  ...
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and do:

```
$("#wrapper input").each(function (index) {
  console.log($(this).val());  
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean $("#wrapper input") ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#<%=FeaturedContent.ClientID%> input").each(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());  
    });
```

Comment: It not in Standlone JS file, I have I am using jquery to get the Textbox individually which works and there fore I have it on the same page. But when I try that it says Error 8 'FeaturedContent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like that in your javascript function :

```
var myAnswers[] = $('.class').Content().ToArray();
```